# converting stringstream to stl containers

Tags: c++, type-conversion, std, stringstream

I want to convert some stringstream to vector, but I lost all my spaces during it.

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    vector<char> data;
    Wrapper(std::stringstream &s) {
        std::cout << s.str();  //output: 22 serialization::archive 16 0 0 2
        for (char c; s >> c;)
            data.push_back(c);

        std::cout << '\n';
        for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
            std::cout << *i; // output: 22serialization::archive1600222
    }
};

...

new Wrapper(stream);
```

Also my conversation method don't looks elegant. Is there are better way to do it?

Comment: The input operator `>>` by default skip spaces. Perhaps you need the [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) manipulator?

Comment: *Or* since you have a *string* stream, just get the string from it and [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) the characters into the vector?

Comment: Converting `sstring` to `string` and than to `vector` will works (I hope). But it looks like double copy of data. How to add `std::noskipws` manipulator?

Comment: You don't need any conversion, just use `s->str()` directly in the call to [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). Also, what is the reason you pass a *pointer* to the stream? Why not a (possibly `const`) reference instead (which is more common)?

Comment: Why are you doing this at all instead of `auto s = stream.str(); vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed pointers to const reference in example. As far as I understand you propose something like `std::copy(s.str().begin(), s.str().end(), data.begin());`. Thi fails for me (seg fault), I supose because two s.str() generate two different objects.

@molbdnilo Ok, it looks good. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), `operator>>` skips spaces by default.

It is possible to directly construct a `std::vector<char>` from a `std::stringstream` using the appropriate overload and a couple of [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 22 << " serialization::archive " << 16 << ' ' << 0 << ' ' << 0 << ' ' << 2;

    std::vector<char> data {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),   // <- default-constructed end of stream iterator
    };

    // it outputs: 22 serialization::archive 16 0 0 2
    for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i;
}
```